When using YouTube Data API v3 always getting quota exceed error
When using YouTube Data API v3 for fetching latest videos (last 24 hours) from a list of around 200+ channels using C#, I am always getting quota exceed error. I am using only the "auth/youtube.readonly" scope. What is the solution to make it working. Or is it not possible to get the list of videos from 200+ channels? Please help.
I am using only the "auth/youtube.readonly" scope. And used paging while calling the api

Do you know what "quota" means?

I am going to assume that you are still only the development quota allotment of 10k quota points.
If you check the page determine_quota_cost  you will see that video.list costs 1 quota points while  search.list costs 100 quota points.
You should be able to calculate how many calls you can make per day based upon your current quota allotment.
quota will reset at midnight west cost USA time if you run out.
